Mui style switch component on check status using the sx prop
Since I've been editing the Mui switch component for quite long time, It came to my mind the following arrangement of nested styles for setting a new style based on a change of the state:
         sx={{
           "& .MuiSwitch-thumb": {
             "& .Mui-checked": {
               color: "#4a3e98",
             },
           },
           "& .MuiSwitch-track": {
             "& .Mui-checked": {
               backgroundColor: "#4a3e98",
             },
           },
         }}


However, this setup has no effect in the overall design. Any ideas to make it work?

Apparently, the state style has to be set as an external layer followed by the component-slot style as a child
        sx={{
          "& .Mui-checked": {
            "& .MuiSwitch-thumb": {
              backgroundColor: "#4a3e98",
            },
            "& .MuiSwitch-track":{
              
            }
          },
        }}

